# Assign an Excel function result to a variable within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet where I'm using VLOOKUP to get data from another sheet.  I have it working, but it's giving me an annoying "0" for blank results.  I'd like to incorporate ISBLANK to address it.

My problem is the syntax.  I REALLY do NOT want to retype the entire VLOOKUP function for the results if it returns FALSE.

In other words, what I'm trying to avoid doing is this:

```
=IF(ISNULL(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2)),"",VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2))
```

Ideally, what I want to do is something like this:

```
=IF(ISNULL(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2)),"",[some variable that stores the result of the VLOOKUP])
```

Ideas, anyone?  Thanks...

Comment: neither [IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isnull-function) - a VBA, not worksheet function - or [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665), which should have a cell as an argument, would work in this case.

Comment: Is a [UDF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) an option?

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to formatting?  You can hide the zeros that way, and therefore keep the formula short.

Highlight the range of the `VLOOKUP()` results, and go to Formatting, then Custom.  Use this format and any `0` will be effectively hidden:

```
0;-0;;@
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you're looking up text or numbers.

If you want the result of your expression to be text that you're looking up, it's as simple as wrapping your `VLOOKUP` with the function `T()`.

So, for **text**, replace  `VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2,FALSE)` with  `T(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2,FALSE))`

If the result of your expression is a number, and your `VLOOKUP` expression is too complicated to repeat, then you can avoid writing it twice by sneakily using `IFERROR`. The trick is to make it so that when `VLOOKUP` returns `0`, it makes an error, but otherwise it returns what `VLOOKUP` returned. And you can do this by taking advantage of some maths: Where `x<>0`, then `1/(1/x) = x`. When `x=0`, Excel returns `#DIV/0!`. If we use `IFERROR`, then we can replace that with an empty string (`""`)

So, for **numbers**, replace `VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2,FALSE)` with `IFERROR(1/(1/VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200,2,FALSE)),"")`

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of it the formula you're asking for is:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:$C$200,2,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet!$B$1:$C$200,2,FALSE))
```

**Edit:**  The `FALSE` at the end of the function is so it only finds an exact match.  Omitting it, or setting it as `True`, returns an exact *or* the next largest value that is less than the lookup value - your list must be sorted in ascending order for that to work.

Note the range reference to the sheet called `Sheet`is `Sheet!$B$1:$C$200` and not `Sheet!$B$1:Sheet!$C$200`.

*Having said that*, an easier way is just to hide the 0 returns with number formatting.
Give the cell a custom number format of:

```
#,##0;-#,##0;;@
```

The first section `#,##0` is the format for positive numbers, the second `-#,##0` for negative numbers, the third `;;`(no format set) for zeros and the last `@` for text.

Comment: Not sure why the -1. Maybe if I added that what the OP _ideally_ wanted isn't possible so it's either what he's trying to avoid or cell formatting.  Afraid there's no `ISERROR` type function for that.

Comment: Umm...  speaking as the OP, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: No problem. Was a couple of years ago now. Forgotten all about it :)